# Is Elon Musk sticking with his promise to deliver Starlink to aid agencies in Gaza, after Israel threatened to "cut all ties" with Starlink in return?

Tags: israel, gaza, starlink

Euronews [reports](https://youtu.be/xJCbM5Gw10c?t=25) that after Elon Musk said Starlink will be delivered to aid agencies in Gaza, Israel said they'll "cut all ties" with the company in retaliation. So, is Starlink sticking with their plan to deliver to Gaza, even though Israel is probably a much bigger market?

Comment: Elon Musk is a private individual and not a politician.  What he does or doesn't do is a business question, not a political one.

Comment: As for now, there are already reports that internet is slowly being restored in Gaza.